# ImportError: No module named 'email.mime'; email is not a package

Tags: python, pip

When running the below code, I keep getting the error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'email.mime'; email is not a package
```

So I run:

```
pip install email
```

And get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'...
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1
```

The internet has told me to run:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

To solve this problem, which I've done many times now. I don't know what else I can do.

Python version: Python 3.3.5 | Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)

```
import smtplib,email,email.encoders,email.mime.text,email.mime.base

smtpserver = 'email@site.com'
to = ['address@gmail.com']
fromAddr = 'email@site.com'
subject = "testing email attachments"

# create html email
html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" '
html +='"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'
html +='<body style="font-size:12px;font-family:Verdana"><p>...</p>'
html += "</body></html>"
emailMsg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart('text/csv')
emailMsg['Subject'] = subject
emailMsg['From'] = fromAddr
emailMsg['To'] = ', '.join(to)
emailMsg['Cc'] = ", ".join(cc)
emailMsg.attach(email.mime.text.MIMEText(html,'html'))

# now attach the file
fileMsg = email.mime.base.MIMEBase('text/csv')
fileMsg.set_payload(file('rsvps.csv').read())
email.encoders.encode_base64(fileMsg)
fileMsg.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment;filename=rsvps.csv')
emailMsg.attach(fileMsg)

# send email
server = smtplib.SMTP(smtpserver)
server.sendmail(fromAddr,to,emailMsg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Comment: Do you have a file (or directory) called `email.py` in the directory where you are running the script? Or is your script even called `email.py`?

Comment: @Evert nope, nothing named email in this directory.

Comment: And have you tried the various imports from the Python prompt? `>>> import email`, `>>> import email.mime`?

Comment: Yes, I have.  - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1517, in _find_and_load_unlocked
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "./email.py", line 4, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/Users/john.houghton/anaconda/envs/py3k/lib/python3.3/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
ImportError: No module named 'email.utils'; email is not a package

Comment: "File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> File "./email.py", line 4": that looks suspiciously like your script is actually called `email.py`.

Comment: @Evert This script is not, however, I did find one in this directory with the name 'email.py', which was a dumb mistake. Now having changed the name of that file, I'm still seeing the same error.

Comment: There's likely a email.pyc file or \_\_pycache\_\_ directory still present which contains the compiled version of that file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93223/discussion-between-super-john-and-evert).

Comment: @Evert Heh, brilliant. That was my problem...

Answer (score 216, accepted):

I encountered the same problem just now. Finally, I found it's because I name the python file as 'email.py'. It works after changing its name.

Comment: Can't believe I felt into this simple trap! But I did!

Comment: found this post and cannot believe this was my issue.

Answer (score 32):

Don't use ***"email"*** in your .py file name or even in package name as well.
This will cause confusion to the interpreter between user declared module and pre-defined modules

Comment: This is one of the most stupid gotachs! Why do we have all the namespaces, packages, modules etc if python isn't able to distinguish between them? :-\

Comment: Strangly the conflict only occurs when an email package is placed directly under src. It goes away when moved into a subdirectory.

Answer (score 21):

The issue is in pip. I was unable to update setuptools using

```
easy_install --upgrade setuptools
```

I was also unable to install email with pip using

```
pip install email
```

I fixed the problem by installing email using easy_install

```
easy_install email
```

Hope someone finds that as helpful. Thanks to those who have helped.

Comment: I also needed to change the import from `import email.Parser` to `from email6.parser import Parser`

Comment: No, this is silly. `email` is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Both answers helped me solve it.
However, in addition I also had to delete the email.pyc file that was created when  the script was run with the old name email.py.

To summarize:

- make sure the email module is installed
- delete the email.pyc file that was created when the script called email.py was run
- rename the script to something else