# How to fix: ModuleNotFoundError at email.mime

Tags: python, email, mime

I'm trying to send an email via SMTP also using pythons email module. Since I want to send a file I'm using the MIME module to get this working.
Unfortunately there is some problem importing these email.mime modules which I can not get fixed.

```
#Imports
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText  
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
import smtplib
import datetime

mail = 'email@address.net'

#E-Mail Content
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = mail
msg['To'] = mail
msg['Subject'] = 'MesseMahlzeiten Backup Nr.{}'.format('1')

body = datetime.datetime.strftime('%Y-&m-%d %H:%M')
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = 'WinIcon.jpg'
attachment = open(filenmae, 'rb')
p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
p.set_payload(attachment.read())
encoders.encode_base64(p)
p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= 
{}".format(filename))
msg.attach(p)

content = msg.as_string()

#E-Mail via SMTP
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttsl()
server.login(mail, 'password')
server.sendmail(mail, mail, content)
server.quit()
```

I'm getting following Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/101testprojects/email/email.py", line 2, in <module>
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
  File "D:\Python\101testprojects\email\email.py", line 2, in <module>
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.mime'; 'email' is not a 
package
```

How can I get this import work?

Comment: Did you try `pip install email` or `easy_install email`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313858/importerror-no-module-named-email-mime-email-is-not-a-package

Comment: Thanks, problem was that the file was called email.py which caused this problem.

Comment: Cool, formalized my comments into an answer for you. If you see value in my answer, you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the name of the file from `email.py` to something else. With the original name, Python tries to import from `email.py`, rather than the `email` module.

Further reading: [ImportError: No module named 'email.mime'; email is not a package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313858/importerror-no-module-named-email-mime-email-is-not-a-package)