# Python email package is not getting imported on Ubuntu machine

Tags: python, ubuntu

I am using from Python prompt in Ubuntu machine, the following is working fine:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
```

However, when I am trying to run the above as a part of script from Ubuntu command prompt or terminal I am getting the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/fraud/app/email.py", line 9, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/home/ubuntu/fraud/app/email.py", line 11, in <module>
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email.mime'; 'email' is not a package
```

Can't really figure out what am I missing here.

Comment: Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313858/importerror-no-module-named-email-mime-email-is-not-a-package

Comment: /home/ubuntu/fraud/app/email.py masks the python standard lib namespace, you should rename it

Comment: @vinzBad: Ahh!! There you go. Fixed it!!!!

Answer (score -1):

had same error few days ago,i just used this instead

```
pip install secure-smtplib
```

Comment: Do you have a file called email.py in your source code? Rename it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313858/importerror-no-module-named-email-mime-email-is-not-a-package